# Finding the coefficient in the Fourier Series is the Discrete Fourier Transform?

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I'm studying Fourier Series and Discrete Fourier Transform, and I have a conceptual question.

The complex form of the Fourier Series is:
$$
f(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{i\omega_n t}
$$
and to find the coefficient the following formula is used:
$$
c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \! f(t) \, e^{-i\omega_n t} \, dt
$$

My question is: Is this formula above the Discrete Fourier Transform or not?

If she is not the Discrete Fourier Transform what is she then?

Comment: Note: the arguments of the exponential functions must have opposite signs. The usual convention is to throw in the minus sign in the second formula that calculates the coefficients.

Comment: Thanks, but would you know the answer to the question?